# Migrate Visual Studio .NET 2003 to 2008

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, migration, legacy-code

I have a legacy solution made in Visual Studio .NET 2003 and I need to migrate it to 2008 so what are the effective steps to do it? Do you know any free aid tools to help making UML diagrams such as activity, collaboration, sequence, etc...? Does anyone know free tools to help understand quickly the code and make the migration process more affordable? Any suggestion on migrating legacy systems?

Comment: Have you tried opening it in VS 2008? It should migrate the project for you, and report any errors encountered. For more details, see [Overview: Converting Visual Studio Web Sites and Projects to Visual Studio 2008](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763180.aspx)

Comment: @RufusL Well in fact I do not need to migrate the entire project to visual studio 2008, only a part so I need to understand it and then migrate this part to vs2008. I was searching for some free aid tool to generate uml diagrams, specially, sequence, activity or collaboration. I am interested in diagrams which provides information on how different objects/classes interact each other.

Comment: Ok. Voting to close based on the criteria: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio should seamlessly support upgrading projects/solutions from previous versions.
Ultimate edition has support for UML diagrams. Trial edition of it is available for 90 days.